# Using variables in VisualStudio Application settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, variables

i have this little problem, i use the Application settings in VS 2010 to configure a path. now it would be convenient if i could add a variable there (its an argument) so it looks like this: C:\EXAMPLEDIR\... is there any way todo this?
Or should i change the settings at startup in code? is this even possible (i would like to avoid this).

thank you.

GuyFawkes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a method that catches the setting. For example SPECIALFOLDER\Subdir... and then replaces the SPECIALFOLDER with an Environment.SpecialFolder. Voila. Now i can e.g. access the system folder in NT, XP and 7. Plus i can add more custom MY VARIABLE items to replace them accordingly.

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the scope from Application to User.  User settings can be modified at runtime.  They are saved if/when you invoke the Save method.